# I need a C# library for zipx

Tags: c#, zip, winzip

I need to extend my application to unzip .zipx files. This appears to be the latest and greatest zip compression from WinZip.

Does anyone know of a library that will do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One thing I would suggest is looking here.

it seems they are open to developers.

http://www.winzip.com/comp_info.htm

Comment: is right. In Download section, you can get the command line, which you can run from C# http://www.winzip.com/downcl.html

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Version_history) WinZip uses `.zipx` as extension for Zip archives that use compression methods newer than [deflate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflate). Deflate is perhaps the minimum standard of Zip which everyone can compress or extract but newer algorithms like [bzip2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2), [LZMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lzma) or [PPMd+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_by_Partial_Matching) are also defined by the [standard](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

As for libraries which are able to handle newer compression algorithms you may have luck with [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) which implements at least bzip2 compression. There is also [DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip) but it seems to be a little low on newer features.

Comment: DotNetZip does DEFLATE. Does not currently do bzip2, LZMA or PPMd.

Comment: That was my fear. Didn't find much definitive info on their page, though.

Comment: (I wrote DotNetZip).  I guess it would be possible to produce an LZMA and PPMd capability but never got a formal request.  I looked at the LZMA SDK but my head spins when I see the code. Feasible, but it will take some effort.

Answer (score 0):

As Johannes Rossel mentioned [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) is a decent compression library written in C# and has source code available. This library is used in various projects as well and seems to have decent support. The only negative aspect is that I don't think they currently support WinZip's new zipx format. In fact I haven't found any other application or library that currently supports this new format other than WinZip. If you need a library for their new format probably the first place to start checking is with the WinZip support department to see if they have a native library available that could be wrapped or some specifications on the new format. If this file format is a closed spec then unfortunately you may not have many options.

Comment: It's still the old format. It's just a kind of marker that the archive uses newer compression algorithms than deflate.