# reading zipx in java

Tags: java, zip

Any suggestions for a tool/object/utility to read a .zipx file in java?

Have already looked at [I need a C# library for zipx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200289/i-need-a-c-library-for-zipx) and http://www.winzip.com/comp_info.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears as though [the ZIPX format is a regular ZIP container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)), just using compression methods other than DEFLATE.

This means you can use Java's regular [ZipFile class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getInputStream(java.util.zip.ZipEntry)) to extract the `byte[]` contents, but depending on the value of [`ZipEntry.getMethod()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getMethod()) you'll have to use non-JDK classes to decompress.

Compression methods and Java support:

- DEFLATE: in JDK
- bzip2: in [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/compressors/bzip2/package-summary.html)
- [Jpeg Compression - Compression Method 96](http://www.winzip.com/comp_info.htm): no Java code, AFAIK
- [WavPack - Compression Method 97](http://www.winzip.com/comp_info.htm): at [WavPack](http://www.wavpack.com/downloads.html#sources)
- [PPMd - Compression Method 98](http://www.winzip.com/comp_info.htm):  no Java, AFAIK
- LZMA: available at http://contrapunctus.net/league/haques/lzmajio/

Note: this is for open-source Java libraries.  It appears [there's commercial, non-open-source libraries](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/compression-java.asp) for all these.

In other words, apart from the above software from [Chilkat software](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/compression-java.asp), you're gonna have to write a bunch of your own code to fully support ZIPX.

Needless to say, the folks at WinZip could add more compression methods at any point, so ZIPX isn't a fixed target.

Comment: thanks for the links. The chilkat component looks cheap enough to save several hours work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any such library, so I think your best bet is to invoke the [WinZip command line](http://www.winzip.com/prodpagecl.htm), using `java.lang.Runtime#exec(..)`